# How much money did Obama's Ebola czar Ron Klain donate to the Democratic Party?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, campaign-finance

I don't need the exact figure, I only want a rough estimation.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, if a little pendantic.

Answer (score 9):

To add to Bobson's actual answer, the subtext of the question is that Klain's nomination may have been influenced by his donations. While not exactly unheard of in Washington, DC; in this case it is clearly evidently NOT the case, as Klain was already an extremely influential political figure in Democratic politics, including in Obama Administration:

- Very extensive government career prior to 2000
- Chief of Staff to VP Al Gore
- possible replacement for White House Chief of Staff Rahm Emanuel
- Chief of Staff to Vice President Joe Biden
- "In 1994, Time named Klain one of the "50 most promising leaders in America" under the age of 40. In 1999, Washingtonian magazine named him the top lawyer in Washington under the age of 40, and the American Bar Association's Barrister magazine named him one of the top 20 young lawyers nationwide."

(src: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Klain)

Comment: I considered adding something like this to my answer, or to a comment on the question, but I didn't feel like making the effort for such a short question.  Thank you for doing so.

Answer (score 8):

**Not all that much.**

OpenSecrets.org [lists](http://www.opensecrets.org/usearch/?q=ron+klain&cx=010677907462955562473%3Anlldkv0jvam&cof=FORID%3A11) $6,200 to three different Democratic politicians this election cycle.  He also donated $1,588 at [Obama's inaugaration](http://www.opensecrets.org/obama/inaug_all.php?name=klain), well below the maximum of $50,000.

Looking at his raw data (from searching [here](http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/norindsea.shtml)), he donated a total of $19,040 since 2001, which averages $1,464 a year. (This doesn't seem to include the inauguration donation, though).

Comment: So, based on that, is getting the title 'Ebola Czar' a reward or punishment? :)

Comment: @DA. - for doing a job that pays extremely well, looks good on a resume, **and doesn't require to actually deliver meaningful results** attributable to one's efforts, definitely a reward.

Comment: @DVK -- it also opens him to substantial criticism if anything goes wrong.  Rumor has it that the reward is the next job, to [succeed Podesta](http://www.politico.com/story/2014/10/ron-klain-white-house-112067.html).

Comment: @Brythan - you mean like he was (not) criticized for all the things gone wrong in prior jobs?

Comment: @DVK  most of his work in previous jobs was relatively private.  Most people don't criticize the adviser to X (Biden, Gore, etc.).  They criticize X directly.  Here, if there's an Ebola problem, people who don't know him are going to blame him even if he had nothing to do with it.  This job leaves him open as the scapegoat.  It's high on responsibility and low on actual power.