# Did any of Ron Klain's positions in 1998-2008 period limit contributions?

Tags: united-states, regulation, campaign-finance

- While answering "[How much money did Obama's Ebola czar Ron Klain donate to the Democratic Party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/how-much-money-did-obamas-ebola-czar-ron-klain-donate-to-the-democratic-party/6214) " I started wondering *why*? He - clearly a very powerful and successful and rich lawyer - donated so little compared to his cohort:

  > In the 2008 election cycle, the industry contributed a massive $234 million to federal political candidates and interests , 76 percent of which went to Democratic candidates and committees. ([opensecrets](https://www.opensecrets.org/industries/indus.php?ind=K01))

  Also, ([NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2000/03/23/us/trial-lawyers-pour-money-into-democrats-chests.html)) and ([Fox News](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2014/04/01/money-from-trial-lawyers-groups-flowing-to-democrats/)), for balance.
- As someone who works in a company that places official restrictions on political donations due to various regulations, it seems possible to me that similar restrictions may have played a role; however, I'm completely unfamiliar with whether any political donation limits exist in government positions that this individual held.
- As such:

  **Are/were there specific restrictions on political donations** for any of the positions that [Wikipedia lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Klain) for Ron Klain for 1998-2008 time period, government or private sector?

Comment: We're assuming that everyone participates in corruption given the chance.

Comment: What's the deal with Ron Klain/Klein? Is this what this site is supposed to be about? Also, is his name “Klain” or “Klein”? As a non-US person, all this seems mysterious…

Comment: @Relaxed - If you read carefully, it's about **general positions he held**, not about him. If you see a misspelling, feel free to edit.

Comment: @DVK As far as I am concerned, it's a distinction without a difference. I never heard of him and just see several questions vaguely related to some obscure US figure popping up so I am just a bit puzzled. And I have no idea what's his name is.

Comment: @Relaxed - if you bother looking at my answer on another question, you'll realize that it's NOT an "obscure figure". And feel free to ignore US-centric questions if you don't like US politics. I added united-states tag to this one.

Comment: @DVK I don't mind so much, I was just genuinely curious and wondering if there was some untold reason he attracted so much attention. Also, I read your answer and I still think it's a pretty obscure figure.

Comment: @Relaxed - beacuse EBOLA!!!! RUN FOR THE HILLS! (or if you were asking why he attracted "attention" on this site, it's because he didn't - he attracted ONE question (and a follow up question because I have a habit of coming up with new questions on whatever topic I'm answering)